# How to prove that the following family of subsets $\mathcal{F}$ is a algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

A set $A$ if finite if #$A$ is finite. A set $A$ is cofinite if #$A^c$ is finite. Let $\Omega$ be a set such that #$\Omega = \infty$. Let be $\mathcal{F}$ a family of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ such that $A$ is finite or cofinite. How to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a algebra but is not a $\sigma$-algebra?

I had tried to solve this problem, but I could not succeed with my solution. 
Especially to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

My solution is:

- If $A$ is finite, then we have:

  (i) $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$, because $\Omega^c$ is cofinite;

  (ii) $A \in \mathcal{F}$, because $A$ is finite. Hence, $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$ because $A^c$ is co-finite;

  (iii) $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$ because they are finite. Hence, $A \cup B \in \mathcal{F}$ because $A\cup B$ is finite;
- If $A$ is cofinite, then we have:

  (i) $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$, because $\Omega^c$ is cofinite;

  (ii) $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$, because $A^c$ is finite. Hence, $A \in \mathcal{F}$ because $A$ is cofinite;

  (iii) $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$ because they are cofinite. Hence, $A \cup B \in \mathcal{F}$ because $A^c\cap B^c$ is finite and using the above statement $\left(A^c\cap B^c\right)^c = A \cup B \in \mathcal{F}$;

Comment: The following may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003552/a-family-of-sets-that-is-not-a-sigma-algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example let $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$ and put $A_i=\{2i\}$ for $i\geq 1$. Then $\cup_i A_i$ is a subset of $\Omega$ that is not finite and not cofinite.